# Blanc page after importing <Home /> componenet

Tags: reactjs

I just started a new React project and created `Home` page, but i got this error :

```
Compiled with warnings.

src\App.jsx
  Line 5:3:  Unreachable code  no-unreachable
```

Even thought i double checked my imports but i can't understand why  can't be imported correctly? I'm still getting a blanc page.

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        Homepage
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**App.jsx**

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";

const App = () => {
  return
  <Home />;     //this is the error spot
};

export default App;
```

**package.json:**

```json
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it like below:

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";

const App = () => {
  return <Home />;
};

export default App;
```

`Note: Remove Enter before Home component!`

Comment: thanks ! but how can an enter make a difference?!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runtimes automatically insert semicolons when the code is being interpreted. The issue here is that since there is a newline after your return statement, the interpreter is inserting a semicolon, which prevents any code after that from executing, including your `<Home />` component.

You can learn more about semicolon insertion [here](https://www.ltvco.com/engineering/semicolon-javascript/)

Comment: yeah right, i noticed that the runtime inserted a semicolone automatically as you said, and i didn't pay it any attention, thanks :)